# Multi-level Mega Menu Full Width Dropdown Issue

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I'm trying to create a multi-level mega menu which is full width but the content within in it has a max-width of 1240px. I can get the content to be the max-width but struggling to make it full width. Trying to replicate something similar to the https://www.boots.com/

Here's what I've got at the moment, any help would be appreciated

```css
.newNavDesktop {
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(302.5deg,#294a77 13.9%,#000338);
  width: 100vw;
}

.newNavDesktopContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-menu {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-menu,.nav-menu ul,.nav-menu li,.nav-menu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -9999px;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s;
  background: grey;
}

.nav-menu li:hover > ul, .nav-menu li:hover > .newWrapContainer .newNavWrap {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.nav-menu ul li:hover >  ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.nav-menu li {
  cursor: default;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 12em;
}

.nav-menu ul li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-menu a {
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #5BC0DE;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu > li > .nav-active {
}

.nav-menu a:hover,.nav-menu a:focus,.nav-menu li:hover a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-menu li li a,.nav-menu li:hover li a {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu li:hover li a:hover,.nav-menu li:hover li a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-menu li:hover li:hover a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.newWrapContainer .newNavWrap {
  background: grey;
  max-width: 1240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.newWrapContainer {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<section class="newNavDesktop"><section class="newNavDesktopContent">
      <ul class="nav-menu nav-center">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-active">Shop By</a>
          <div class="newWrapContainer">
          <ul class="newNavWrap">
            <li><a href="#">Nav Cat 1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav Cat 1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav Cat 1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav Cat 1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-active">Shop By Category</a>
<div class="newWrapContainer">
          <ul class="newNavWrap">
            <li><a href="#">Nav Cat 2</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav Cat 2</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav Cat 2</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav Cat 2</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav Cat 2</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
</div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-active">Shop By Brand</a>
<div class="newWrapContainer">
          <ul class="newNavWrap">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Nav Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section></section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your wrapper (`.newNavDesktop`) for the menu and apply `width: 100vw` with CSS, which will make it cover the whole width of the viewport, always. Apply the same `width: 100vw` to the dropdown element. Here I'd introduce a div around the dropdown list for that matter.

The ul itself can then have a `max-width: 1024px`. That way the dropdown can have a grey background and span the whole screen, while the list only spans 1024px at max.

I created a Codepen to better illustrate what I think is the solution to your question: https://codepen.io/Nice2MeatU/pen/ZEpLdbK

Comment: Hi Marco thanks for your reply. But what i'm trying to do is make the dropdown when hovered to be full width but with the content to be a max-width of 1240px i.e the grey dropdown that appears. @Marco Hengstenberg

Comment: Okay, then I misunderstood your question. Yet, the answer still applies. The nav itself needs to be full width, the dropdown needs to be full-width too and the <ul> can then have a max-width. I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've made the suggestions you've mentioned but it's still not working or maybe i've not implemented them right. I've amended my code above if you could take a look.

Comment: Alright. Question: do you want the dropdown lists to sit beneath their respective triggers (the links which need to be hovered)?

Comment: I updated my Codepen. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: If you look at the mega menu on https://www.boots.com/ this is how i want the dropdown. So the dropdown would open up in full width but the content in the dropdown will always be at a max width of 1240px. then the multi-level categories go from left to right.

Comment: Codepen updated again. Click on the links to reveal the dropdowns. You won't get away with CSS alone on this one though if the top-level links need to point at pages and not only act as a trigger for the dropdowns. In this case I'd suggest to go with a bit of JS feature-detection and if JS is available replace the links with proper button elements and do the reveal of the dropdown with JS.